# Find last corresponding date to for a string value in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe df

| date | letter |
| --- | --- |
| June 1 | A |
| June 2 | B |
| June 3 | C |
| June 4 | B |
| June 5 | A |

I want to add a column with the most recent previous date that the letter appeared:

| date | letter | last_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| June 1 | A |  |
| June 2 | B |  |
| June 3 | C |  |
| June 4 | B | June 2 |
| June 5 | A | June 1 |

I am kind of stumped on this. Tried different ideas but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataframe is sorted by `date`:

```py
m = df[df.duplicated("letter", keep="last")].set_index("letter")["date"]
df["last_date"] = df.loc[df[::-1].duplicated("letter", keep="last"), "letter"].map(m)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     date letter last_date
0  June 1      A       NaN
1  June 2      B       NaN
2  June 3      C       NaN
3  June 4      B    June 2
4  June 5      A    June 1
```

---

OR: Using `.groupby`:

```py
def fn(g):
    if len(g) == 1:
        g["last_date"] = np.nan
        return g

    g["last_date"] = [np.nan] * (len(g) - 1) + [g["date"].iat[0]]
    return g


df = df.groupby("letter", sort=False, group_keys=False).apply(fn)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

groupby + shift

```
df.assign(last_date=df.groupby('letter')['date'].shift())
```

output:

```
    date    letter  last_date
0   June 1  A       NaN
1   June 2  B       NaN
2   June 3  C       NaN
3   June 4  B       June 2
4   June 5  A       June 1
```

---

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'date': ['June 1', 'June 2', 'June 3', 'June 4', 'June 5'], 
         'letter': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Comment: thanks. I was trying something like this but kept having problems. I would shift things from one group to another

Answer (score 0):

### If you don't want to use pandas API

```
import pandas as pd


EMPTY = ''

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'date': ['June 1', 'June 2', 'June 3', 'June 4', 'June 5'],
        'letter': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A'],
    },
)


result = []
mapping = {}  # {[letter]: date}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    result.append(mapping.get(row['letter'], EMPTY))
    mapping[row['letter']] = row['date']
df['last_date'] = result


print(df)
'''
     date letter last_date
0  June 1      A          
1  June 2      B          
2  June 3      C          
3  June 4      B    June 2
4  June 5      A    June 1
'''
```

Comment: thanks. I think pandas API would be easier